¿Qué significa Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, e); dentro del bloque catch?
Estamos revisando el tema de excepciones en Java y me puse a investigar un poco más por mi cuenta y topé con un fragmento de código que jamás había visto:
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        OutputStream datos = new FileOutputStream("datos.txt");

        for(var i = 0x30; i <= 0x39; i++){
            datos.write(i);
        }
        datos.flush();

        datos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){

        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, e);

    } catch (IOException e){

        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, e);

    }
}

Particularmente la línea que es totalmente nueva para mí (y que no logro entender) es esta
Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, e);

¿Qué significa toda esa línea?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! La clase Logger en general genera un archivo de log (dependiendo de su configuracion) y ahi le pasa el nombre de la clase que genero el error, el tipo de error, y tambien todo el error en si (la e)

Hola victor, bienvenido, podes mirar acá, para una explicación más a fondo.

En resumidas cuentas lo que hace es escribir en el log de la aplicación la excepción que se ha producido para que puedas ver en que punto de la ejecución ha ocurrido y detalles de por qué ha pasado para que puedas poner una solución al problema.
Vamos a refactorizar el código en dos sentencias para que lo veas más claro. Estarás de acuerdo que tu código es prácticamente equivalente a este:
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

En esta parte:
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

le estás pidiendo a la clase Logger que te de un logger con el nombre de la clase en la que estás trabajando. Si el logger no existe, lo crea, y si ya existía te da el que se había creado antes. Este logger es un objeto al que le puedes pedir que te escriba cosas en el log de la aplicación.
El motivo de ponerle el nombre de la clase es que lo va a escribir en cada línea del log para que sepas qué clase está produciendo ese mensaje. También sirve para tomar decisiones en función del nombre de logger, por ejemplo podrías hacer que todo lo que sea relativo a la clase Main se escriba en "Main.log" y todo lo sea relativo al resto de las clases lo escriba en "application.log".
El motivo por el que pone Main.class.getName() en lugar de simplemente "Main" es porque si cambias el nombre de tu clase a "Pepe", a tu IDE le va a ser más fácil cambiarlo a Pepe.class.getName() ya que no va a saber si "Main" es el nombre de tu clase o una cadena que se casualmente se llama "Main" y no se va a arriesgar a cambiarle el contenido.
Una vez tienes el logger, en esta otra parte:
logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);

lo que le estás pidiendo es que escriba en el log con un nivel de incidencia severo la excepción que has obtenido.
Este método acepta tres parámetros, el primero es el nivel de incidencia, esto sirve para poder filtrar los mensajes de error, una incidencia de nivel severo va a ser visible casi siempre, y es lo recomendable para mensajes de error.
El segundo parámetro es un pequeño mensaje de error que puedes añadir para dar pistas de por qué está pasando. Tu IDE lo ha dejado a null porque no sabe que escribir, pero ahí tu deberías poner algo tipo "No se ha encontrado datos.txt" y "No se ha podido escribir en datos.txt" para que al leer el log no veas simplemente una excepción cruda y te ayude a solucionar el problema.
El tercer parámetro es la excepción que estás obteniendo, con ese objeto el logger es capaz de escribir una traza de error donde puedes ver la pila de la aplicación y ver por qué metodos ha pasado el flujo de la aplicación.
Idealmente, en cada catch deberías hacer algo más que escribir la traza de error, ya que muchas excepciones son "salvables" en el sentido de que no es necesario que la aplicación acabe abruptamente solo porque se hayan producido. Por ejemplo, en tu caso se podría producir una excepción si el disco se llena como consecuencia de escribir en el fichero. Ahí te puedes plantear si te interesa que la aplicación acabe o informar al usuario "El disco está lleno, libere espacio y pulse ENTER para continuar" o algo parecido.
Más información:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html

